# Passing Parameters to jquery ready handler

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would like to create a single function to automate htmlwireups.  Some portions of the page are loaded using ajax and I would like to call a single function to ready both the document and the lazily loaded sections.

Example:

```
function WireHtml(target){
    $(target).ready(function(target){

        // call anything you would normally wire in a standard ready
        // but only on the descendants of the target node such as wiring up
        // an accordion
        $(target).find(".accordion").accordion();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply pass the `target` variable through to the inner function without referencing it in the jQuery `ready` call.

```
function WireHtml(target){
    $(function(){ // <- note the lack of "target" references

        // call anything you would normally wire in a standard ready
        // but only on the descendants of the target node such as wiring up
        // an accordion
        $(target).find(".accordion").accordion();

    });
}
```

The `target` variable will be available within the function that's attached to the ready handler due to a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures).

Side note, `$(document).ready(yourFunction)` or `$(yourFunction)` are preferred to `$().ready(yourFunction)`, though they are all equivalent.

Comment: I'm not confident that `$().ready` works. `$()` will return an empty jQuery object, so binding event handlers to it should have no effect.

Comment: `$().ready(function() { alert(1); });` When does the callback function execute? Immediately?

Comment: @jball I was asking because jQuery - since version 1.4 - no longer transforms `$()` into `$(document)`. Therefore, it could be that `$().ready()` doesn't bind to the DOM ready event.

Comment: @Šime Vidas - ah, I get what you're saying. According to the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), it's discouraged, but should work. Quote: "All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:

1. `$(document).ready(handler)`
2. `$().ready(handler)` (this is not recommended)
3. `$(handler)`"